# Deploy contract to Parity dev chain using Remix

Tags: remix, parity

I'm trying to deploy a contract via remix to my local development chain. However, the transaction never gets mined and is pending forever. When I use a node script it works (at least I receive the contracts address).

I've started a local Parity dev chain with the following command:
`parity --config dev-insecure --jsonrpc-apis=personal,net,eth,rpc,private,parity --jsonrpc-cors "https://remix.ethereum.org"`

Then I unlock the account:
`curl --data '{"method":"personal_unlockAccount","params":["0x00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72","",null],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545`

Now I open `https://remix.ethereum.org` and connect to my local web3 provider. This works and the unlocked account is preselected.

Then I use this test contract: https://pastebin.com/zyLjhJak
and click on deploy.

The transaction is pending forever.

**I guess this has something to do with my Parity config.** Any ideas what I'm missing?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It's sometimes working and sometimes not. If it hangs, I have to restart Parity and reconnect Remix. That's not very satisfying but I can't see another solution right now.